# If x and y are true do this, else do this. Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement, conditional-statements

```
enter code here if fluadf['CLINICAL_STATUS'] = 'DRAFT' and fluadf['CLINICAL_DATE_RECEIVED'] = " / /
```

"
fluadf['CLINICAL_STATUS'].str.replace(
'DRAFT', 'IN TRANSIT')
else
fluadf['CLINICAL_STATUS'].str.replace(
'DRAFT', 'IN PROCESS')

Not sure if this code makes sense. I am trying to test for two values and if they are both true (clinical status is draft and there is not a date for clinical date received) then change draft to in transit. Else, change draft to in process. I'd really appreciate any help coaching me through this.

Comment: Have a look at numpy.where (https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)

Comment: Can you add some data sample, [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with chain both mask by `&` for bitwise `and` and add `()` because precedence of operators:

```
mask = (fluadf['CLINICAL_STATUS'] == 'DRAFT') & (fluadf['CLINICAL_DATE_RECEIVED'] == " / /")

fluadf['CLINICAL_STATUS'] = np.where(mask, 'IN TRANSIT','IN PROCESS')
```

Comment: File "<ipython-input-10-f3e25f7426f5>", line 29
    mask = (fluadf['CLINICAL_STATUS'] = 'DRAFT') & (fluadf['CLINICAL_DATE_RECEIVED'] = " / /")
                                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: I tried that and got this error. I can try and add the minimal, complete, and verifiable example now too. Thanks for the guidance!

Comment: looks like the = between clinical status and draft need to be ==, then it works! Thanks so much Jezrael

Comment: @LGumbleton - You are right, it was my typo. Tahnk you.